# Group item and summary for the same item name in SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has the same Item name but has different Item code, because Item name has 02 part, part 1 has the same name but part 2 has diffrent name.
The result return by this below query:

```
select PO番号 as PONO,商品CD as ITEM_CD,品名1 as ITEM_NAME,[数量]as QTY 
from [ENVIETNAMPO].[dbo].[TBL_PO_M] 
where  PO番号='GV07182'
```

[image]

I need to group all item with the same name but different Item code, and summary for those.

My desired result will looks like:

[image]
 QTY of second row is: 2279 by sum qty from row 2 to row 10. 
I used this query to eliminate the duplicated Item name:

```
 WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [GOODS CD],[Item No.] ORDER BY [GOODS CD],[Item No.]) AS RN
    FROM #tmptable
    )

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN<>1
```

But the problem is I could not get only 02 rows as my desired result. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * into #TempA
from 
( Select m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME,Sum(m.QTY) as Total,
            dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME ORDER BY m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME) AS RN from
    (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PONO,ITEM_NAME ORDER BY PONO,ITEM_NAME) AS RN
        FROM [Tbl_PO_m] 
    )m
    group by  m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME
)A
Select * from 
(
    Select distinct  m.PONO,m.ITEM_CD,m.ITEM_NAME,a.Total,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  m.ITEM_NAME  ORDER BY  m.ITEM_NAME ) AS RN
    FROM [Tbl_PO_m] m
    inner join #TempA a on a.ITEM_NAME = m.ITEM_NAME
)A 
where RN  = 1
```

Comment: I need to add a PONO parameter. Where can I put it? Example: Where PO='GV01234'

Comment: PO番号 商品CD 品名1 Total RN
GV07204 332462311 SN0042TE-SA Wﾎﾞｰｲﾌﾚﾝ 2279 1
GV07683 332393841 WT0040TE-EU RFID_UJ_ 2279 1  .Instead of 2 row must have the same PONO: GV01782 but the output has wrong PONO

Comment: use add filter PO='GV01234'  in where clause of the last query

Comment: ItemCD, ItemName, QTY are correct but PONO is wrong. I query PONO='GV01782' but the result has 02 random PONO

Comment: update query 

Select * from 
(
 Select distinct  m.PONO,m.ITEM_CD,m.ITEM_NAME,a.Total,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME  ORDER BY  m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME ) AS RN
 FROM [Tbl_PO_m] m
 inner join #TempA a on a.ITEM_NAME = m.ITEM_NAME
)A 
where PONO ='GV07184' and RN  = 1

Comment: in above comment, I changed a query to partition the data properly the below ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME ORDER BY m.PONO,m.ITEM_NAME ) AS RN